# Python Blackjack - Count Hand of Players

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I'm trying to count the hands of multiple players and compare them to each other.

Here's my main code:

```
def make_deck():
    # Randomly shuffle a deck
    import random
    cards = []
    for suit in ['H', 'C', 'S', 'D']:
        for num in ['A', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', 'T', 'J', 'Q',
                'K']:
            cards.append(num + suit)
    random.shuffle(cards)
    return cards
deck = make_deck()


num_of_players = int(input("How many players?: "))

def deal_blackjack(deck, num_of_players):
    # Deal two cards to a number of players
    hands = [[] for p in range(num_of_players)]
    i = -1
    for k in range(0,2):
        for h in hands:
            i += 1
            h.append(deck[i])
    return hands

pHands = deal_blackjack(deck, num_of_players)


def print_blackjack(pHands):
    # Prints Players with respective hand
    for i in range(len(pHands)):
        print('Player', i, ':', pHands[i])

def get_max(pHands): 
#Where I'm stuck at
    for i in range(pHands):
        total = 0

        pTotal = int(pHands[i][x][0])
```

I know I have to use pHands and a loop to get the first character of each hand, and convert it to an int ex. int(pHands[i #of hand][x #of 1st str][0]) And then add it onto total

But I can't seem to figure how to implement it for each hand of a player.

ex. 4 Players

Player 0 : ['3S', 'JH'] total = 13

Player 1 : ['6C', 'JC'] total = 16

Player 2 : ['4H', '5D'] total = 9

Player 3 : ['7D', 'AC'] total = 18

### #

Also, I want to compare each hand and select a winner (where an asterisk appears beside the hand).

### #

ex. 4 Players

Player 0 : ['3S', 'JH']

Player 1 : ['6C', 'JC']

Player 2 : ['4H', '5D']

Player 3 : ['7D', 'AC'] *

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your code and accurately describe the problem.  
StackOverflow is not a coding or tutorial service.
Specifically, get rid of the fluff before **get_max** and write a short test routine that isolates its operation.  Then write a function to evaluate a single hand; call it from your loop in **get_hand**.  When you get stuck actually *writing* code, post your efforts here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should create a method called `calculate_hand` then do your work in there.

```
scores = {"A":1, "T":10, "J": 10, "K":10, "Q": 10, }
def calculate_hand(hand):
    hand_value = 0
    ace = False
    for card in hand:
        if card[0] == "A":
            ace =True;
        if card[:-1] in scores:  #used [:-1] insted of [0] because at first, thought it is 10 instead of T
            hand_value += scores[card[:-1]]
        else:
            hand_value += int(card[:-1])
    if ace and hand_value + 10 < 22:
        hand_value += 10
    return hand_value

hand1 = ['AD', 'AC']
hand2 = ['6C', 'JC']
hand3 = ['7D', 'AC']   
value1 = calculate_hand(hand1) #12
value2 = calculate_hand(hand2) #16
value3 = calculate_hand(hand3) #18
```

After you calculate each hand, it's just a simple comparing values returned from `calculate_hand`.

```
print max(value1,value2,value3) #18
```

You should implement these into your code easily.

Answer (score 1):

```
cards_dict = {'A':1, '2':2, '3':3, '4':4, '5':5, '6':6, '7':7, '8':8, '9':9, 'T':10, 'J':11, 'Q':12,'K':13}
def card_to_value(card):
    return cards_dict[card[1]]

def get_max(pHands): 
   for i in range(len(pHands)):
      pCards = pHands[i]
      pTotal[i] = card_to_value(pCards[0]) + card_to_value(pCards[1])
   return pTotal

def winner(pTotal):
    biggest_hand = max(pTotal)
    #if its a tie
    if pTotal.count(biggest_hand) > 1:
        #i don't know what happens
    else:
        return pTotal.index(biggest_hand)
```

Comment: Have you ever played blackjack? `'A:1, J':11, 'Q':12,'K':13`